# Python: Suplots with secondary-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote the following code below to do the following graph:
[image]

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.patch.set_facecolor('white')
ax.plot(df.index, df.X1.values, 'b',
        label='NMA', linewidth=1.5)
ax.set_ylabel('Index')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df.index, df.Y.values, 'r--',
         label='Rate', linewidth=1.5)
ax2.set_ylabel('Rate')
lines = ax.get_lines() + ax2.get_lines()
lgd = ax.legend(lines, [line.get_label() for line in lines],
                loc='lower center', ncol=2, bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.15),
                frameon=False)
ax.set_title('Economic Rate and Index',
             weight='bold')
for i in range(5):
    plt.axvspan(Dates['Peak'][i], Dates['Trough'][i],
                facecolor='grey', alpha=0.5)
plt.grid(False)
plt.savefig('C:\\test.pdf',
            bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight')
```

I am having a hard time to reproduce this figure in a subplot (2X2). The only thing I would change in each of the subplots is the blue line (X1 in `df`... for X2, X3...). How can I have a 2X2 subplot of the above graph? Of Course I would only keep one legend at the bottom of the subplots. Thanks for the help.

The data is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/31s7mbm2q1ybfav/test_data.csv?dl=0) and the "Dates" to reproduce the gray bars [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sn8tjrkewo47ub3/Dates.txt?dl=0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you could create a 2x2 raster with twinx each:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ((ax1a, ax2a), (ax3a, ax4a)) = plt.subplots(2, 2)

ax1b = ax1a.twinx()
ax2b = ax2a.twinx()
ax3b = ax3a.twinx()
ax4b = ax4a.twinx()

ax1a.set_ylabel('ax1a')
ax2a.set_ylabel('ax2a')
ax3a.set_ylabel('ax3a')
ax4a.set_ylabel('ax4a')
ax1b.set_ylabel('ax1b')
ax2b.set_ylabel('ax2b')
ax3b.set_ylabel('ax3b')
ax4b.set_ylabel('ax4b')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: I posted an additional question here where maybe you can help out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457731/python-suplots-with-two-secondary-axis